# Find maximum value from custom html pasted in textarea using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having some custom html pasted in textarea and want to find out the maximum value of intensity tag from that custom html. Please take a look at my try and suggest me what I am doing wrong here.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var $intensity = $("<div/>").html($('.textarea').val()).find("intensity").find("intensity").map(function(){
           return $.trim($(this).text());
        }).get().join(",");

console.log($intensity);
// It can access all available values that are: 64, 88, 32, 53.

$('input[name="max_value"]').val(Math.max.apply(Math, $intensity).toArray());
// This should show the maximum intensity value i.e. 88
});
```

```html
<textarea class='textarea'>
<intensity><theta>28</theta><da>4.0</da><intensity>64</intensity><h>1</h></intensity>
<intensity><theta>32</theta><da>1.3</da><intensity>88</intensity><h>1</h></intensity>
<intensity><theta>21</theta><da>3.8</da><intensity>32</intensity><h>1</h></intensity>
<intensity><theta>46</theta><da>2.4</da><intensity>53</intensity><h>1</h></intensity>
</textarea>
<input name='max_value'>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do several steps like the code below

demo jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lensz7bu/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // 01 - get value (string) 
  let valText = $('.textarea').val()
  console.log(valText);
  
  // 02 - split text => to be array or list
  let splits =  valText.split("\n");
  console.log(splits);
  
  // 03 - filter and map to get value intensity
  let valMaps = splits.filter(function(i) {
    return (i == "" || i.length < 1) ? false : true
  }).map(function(e){        
    // get value intensity
    let reg =  e.match(/<\/da><intensity>(.*?)<\/intensity><h>/)
    if (reg != null) {
        return parseFloat(reg[1])
    }
  })
  
    console.log(valMaps)
  
  // 04 get max malue from array map
  let maxValue = Math.max(...valMaps)
    console.log(maxValue)
  
  // set to html input
  $('input[name="max_value"]').val(maxValue)
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class='textarea'>
<intensity><theta>28</theta><da>4.0</da><intensity>64</intensity><h>1</h></intensity>
<intensity><theta>32</theta><da>1.3</da><intensity>88</intensity><h>1</h></intensity>
<intensity><theta>21</theta><da>3.8</da><intensity>65</intensity><h>1</h></intensity>
<intensity><theta>46</theta><da>2.4</da><intensity>53</intensity><h>1</h></intensity>
</textarea>
<input name='max_value'>
```

Comment: Sir, Thank you for your reply but you have split text based on next line but it is not always true when custom html is pasted in textarea. It should split function irrespective of next line just based on some find function or something which does not depend on next line.

Comment: i just copied from your html code, and if not based on the next line, you just change it with the last tag of the html item. eg `valText.split("/h></intensity>")` demo : https://jsfiddle.net/hk9r6a2p/1/

Comment: i 've added a `i.trim()` function in the filter section to ignore empty ones

Comment: Sir, Thank you so much for all your replies. I am wondering if e.match can be perform independent of exactly locating the vales and .find("intensity") can be used in its place. for example, let 
reg =  e.match($('.textarea').val().find("intensity").find("intensity")) because I want to find intensity inside intensity irrespective of its around text. Again thank you for all your replies

Comment: I think this problem is about string data manipulation. So I think the best solution is to use regex instead of DOM manipulation. jQuery helps you to make managing the DOM easier

Comment: this code can be used to find the intensity inside intensity values:
var $intensity = $("<div/>").html($('.textarea').val()).find("intensity").find("intensity").map(function(){
               return $.trim($(this).text());
            }).get().join(",");

Comment: Can this these comma-separated values be used to find the maximum value?

Comment: Please check my updated question there I have added on getting comma-seperated intensity values

Comment: 1. parseFloat cast data type; 2. delete join; 3. find max value Math.max(...$intensity) | like this https://jsfiddle.net/fu93h57r/